# What makes it impossible to use EJB injection in my WAB?

Tags: java, osgi, glassfish-3, war, ejb-3.1

I try to access a @singleton EJB from my WAB, and it failed with an "Inconsistent Module State" error.

I have created a Web Archive Bundle, so far everything works well. But I want to access to an EJB I have just created.

I am using injection in my servlet listener like that :

```
@EJB(name="Config")
private Configuration config;
```

When I deploy my WAB as an simple WAR, the injection works, but the OSGI Activator is not activated (and this is normal).

If I deploy my WAB as a WAB, the OSGI Activator is activated, the servlet listener is fired, but the injection doesn't works, then the deployement fail with this stack trace :

```
    [#|2012-02-26T00:39:34.172+0100|WARNING|glassfish3.1.1|org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase|_ThreadID=26;_ThreadName=Thread-3;|Failed to deploy bundle WABPluginToto [366]
org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase.DeploymentException: Deployment of WABPluginToto [366] failed because of following reason: Failed while deploying bundle WABPluginToto [366] : java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to deploy bundle [ WABPluginToto [366] ], root cause: Exception while loading the app
    at org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase.AbstractOSGiDeployer.deploy(AbstractOSGiDeployer.java:125)
    at org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase.OSGiContainer.deploy(OSGiContainer.java:154)
    at org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase.JavaEEExtender.deploy(JavaEEExtender.java:107)
    at org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase.JavaEEExtender.access$200(JavaEEExtender.java:61)
    at org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase.JavaEEExtender$HybridBundleTrackerCustomizer$1.call(JavaEEExtender.java:151)
    at org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase.JavaEEExtender$HybridBundleTrackerCustomizer$1.call(JavaEEExtender.java:148)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to deploy bundle [ WABPluginToto [366] ], root cause: Exception while loading the app
    at org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase.OSGiDeploymentRequest.deploy(OSGiDeploymentRequest.java:196)
    at org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase.OSGiDeploymentRequest.execute(OSGiDeploymentRequest.java:118)
    at org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase.AbstractOSGiDeployer.deploy(AbstractOSGiDeployer.java:121)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: Error in linking security policy for WABPluginToto_1.0.0.SNAPSHOT -- Inconsistent Module State
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.SecurityUtil.linkPolicyFile(SecurityUtil.java:337)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.SecurityDeployer.linkPolicies(SecurityDeployer.java:279)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.SecurityDeployer.access$100(SecurityDeployer.java:81)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.SecurityDeployer$AppDeployEventListener.event(SecurityDeployer.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:128)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:270)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase.OSGiDeploymentRequest.deploy(OSGiDeploymentRequest.java:183)
    ... 12 more
```

And I don't really understand why.

I have an other problem: if I try to use the injection in the OSGI Activator, the property is always null.

How can I use my EJB in the OSGI instance ?

Thanks for all.